# How can i install nvidia geforce gtx 580 graphic driver for ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I need to install the graphic driver for my computer so I can play games.

I have tried downloading from the official Nvidia website but I am not able to install it because of `wrong coding` or something?

I have tried to install drivers from `software and updates` -> `additional drivers` but I don't know which one to install.

I have tried installing a few but when I restart the computer I get an error/black screen.

Some screenshot below for more information:

[image: My computer]

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal 
(press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Now execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

In case you still get errors or a black screen, perform the installation this way :

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, enter user name and password.

Now execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, enter user name and password.

Now execute these commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answer. i did the sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install nvidia-352. and i rebootet and got black screen with a | blinking thing.  So i reinstalled ubuntu because i don't know what else to do.


What do you mean by Highlighting the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu?

Comment: @Kristoffer : This time please try to install the drivers using the alternative method - with highlight I mean select the option 'Try Ubuntu without installing' and when it is marked (highlighted) ... press the 'E' key. :)

Comment: Hello again. i tried to do the second step you explained but i still get black screen. 

i put noveau.modeset=0 on the linux line thing and then pressed F10 and logged into my account. and typed sudo apt-get pruge nvidia* and rebooted and typed the command nouveau.modeset=0 again and logged in and then typed sudo apt-get update / sudo apt-get install nvidia-352. rebooted and i got a black screen with a blinking _ .  so i reinstalled ubuntu. Did i do something wrong or is there anything else i can do to install graphic driver ?

Comment: @Kristoffer : Maybe you have to adjust graphics settings in BIOS ... otherwise I am running out of ideas ... this really should have worked ... :)